# Run an EXE from a different directory?

Tags: cmd

After a bit of googling and searching here, couldn't find the answer to this silly question!

For a structure like this...

```
dirZero
|---dirOne
|---|---myProgram.exe
```

How do I run "myProgram" if my current directory is dirZero?  I.E.,

```
C:\dirZero> dirOne/myProgram.exe
```

...which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: the interesting part is that if myProgram was in dirZero and you were in dirOne, then you could do `"..\myProgram.exe"` and it would run the EXE in the previous directory.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You should use a backslash `\`, instead of forward slash. `/`

```
C:\dirZero> dirOne\myProgram.exe
```

Or, wrap it with double quotes `"`

```
C:\dirZero> "dirOne/myProgram.exe"
```

Comment: I think you should move the second one with double quotes to the top as it  is more intuitive for people who are looking for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wrote a Python script in Linux that contains code to call some binaries in other directories. I recently tried to run the same script in Windows and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working until I read this answer - solved my problem. +1.

Comment: Does anyone know what CWD for the program is set to in this case? Is it `C:\dirZero` or `C:\dirZero\dirOne`?

Answer (score 16):

Use a **backslash** instead

```
C:\dirZero> dirOne\myProgram.exe
```

Answer (score -6):

probably u should just simple use

```
cd C:\dirZero\dirOne
C:\dirZero\dirOne> myProgram.exe
```

Comment: This is not the question being asked. Read it more carefully.

Comment: And in some cases it will do different result, as working directory would be different. 

For example if you call npm/yarn

Comment: See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)