# How do I run a command line tool from a different directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to build a C++ application that makes a bunch of command line calls on the Windows command prompt using the `system()` function. The C++ runs in directory *BSP* below. *BSP* contains a sub-folder *BSP/XST/Files*. One of the commands the application makes, needs to call a command line tool (Xilinx Synthesis tools) that needs to run in the *Files* directory.

```
BSP
|---XST
|---|---Files
```

Doing it manually on the command prompt I would do something similar to:

```
>>cd XST
>>cd Files
>>xst -h
```

Is there a way to call a tool in the sub-directory from the *BSP* directory?
I looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903288/run-an-exe-from-a-different-directory), but it does not work. I'm guessing because they are talking about an executable that is stored within the sub-directory whereas I am calling a command line tool (i.e. uses environment variables).

To simplify: Is there a command/option to run a command line tool in a sub-folder on the Windows command prompt? I can just emulate the statement via my C++.

Comment: You specify the full path to the tool. Or are you talking about setting the application's working directory? You can call the `SetCurrentDirectory` function.

Comment: As its not answering your question as such i'll leave this as a comment. If you're only working on windows I'd recommend using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) as this lets you specify all the various parameters when you spawn a process including its working directory, etc.

Comment: @MikeVine that looks really interesting. Thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @CodyGray in the comments, my idea was to use [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx). If your program is located in the *BST* directory and you want to run *xst* in the sub-folder *XST\Files* relative to it, then it makes sense to also use [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx). Use this function to retrieve the path to your program and then replace the file name by your sub-folder. Finally change directory to the modified path:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Get the path to your program.
    char moduleFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, moduleFilePath, MAX_PATH);

    // Find the backslash in front of the name of your program.
    string::size_type pos = string(moduleFilePath).rfind("\\");

    // Replace the program name by your sub-folder.
    string subFolderPath = string(moduleFilePath).substr(0, pos) + "\\XST\\Files";

    // Change into the sub-folder relative to your program.
    SetCurrentDirectory(subFolderPath.c_str());

    // Execute some program in your sub-folder.
    system("type test.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

As I don't have *xst*, I put a text file *test.txt* into the sub-folder for testing purposes. The file just contains `Test test test`, so the program above prints out the following:

> Test test test

But as suggested by @MikeVine, [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) might be a smarter solution.